# Adding Interaction Behavior to Hyperlink inside RichTextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a `RichTextBlock` with a `Hyperlink`.

I would like to execute a `Command` from my ViewModel when the Hyperlink is clicked, so I used a Interaction `Behavior` from **Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors**:

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink>
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction
                        Command="{Binding ShowDocumentCommand}" />
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Hyperlink.Inlines>
                <Run Text="Some link" />
            </Hyperlink.Inlines>
        </Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

But it doesn't work. It runs, but nothing happens. The command isn't executed when the `Hyperlink` is clicked.

Why?
What should I do to make it execute the command?

Comment: It looks like Behaviors can be only attached to the classes derived from FrameworkElement. But Hyperlink does not inherit from it.

Comment: OK. Then, is there a good way to invoke a command from on click other than adding a handler in the code-behind?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Behaviors can be only attached to the classes derived from FrameworkElement. But Hyperlink does not inherit from it.

You can simply use [HyperlinkExtensions](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/HyperlinkExtensions) from UWP Community Toolkit package, which already has the required attached properties `Command` and `CommandParameter`. Or you can just copy-paste their code from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/HyperlinkExtensions.cs).

So your code will look like that:

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Hyperlink xaml:HyperlinkExtensions.Command="{Binding ShowDocumentCommand}">
            <Hyperlink.Inlines>
                <Run Text="Some link" />
            </Hyperlink.Inlines>
        </Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```